# response.addHeader() not adding

Tags: jsp, header, response

I'm using   response.addHeader()   to return random values to the client from a jsp. The method works from time to time, when it doesn't even right after, for example,

```
response.addHeader("x","y")
```

the following returns null

```
response.getHeader("x");
```

I've noticed that it doesn't add any value after a for loop in the jsp, but before the for loop, response.addHeader() works.

Anyone a clue on why this happens and how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: You have to call it before any part of the response body has been committed.

Comment: In my case, i needed to call it after all the codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed to be a problem with the buffer size of the response (or the page). I solved my problem by adding the following line as first line in the page(jsp)

```
response.setBuffer(64000);
```